# Minipage Figure Caption Alignment

Tags: floats, minipage

The alignment is broken when a long caption is there. How to fix?

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{images/Image_34}
  \caption{{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont spy} Plot of 4-bus Test System
  \label{fig:Image_34}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{images/Image_001}
  \caption{{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont spy} Plot of 4-bus Test System load buses only \label{fig:Image_001}}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to align the images and captions independently, use a tabular, but you **must** put the captions in `\parbox`es or `minipage`s.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}% debugging tool
\begin{document}

\newlength{\halfwidth}
\setlength{\halfwidth}{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\halfwidth}p{\halfwidth}@{}}
  \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-4x3}}&
    \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-1x1}}\\
  \caption{{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont spy} Plot of 4-bus Test System}\label{fig:Image_34}&
  \caption{{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont spy} Plot of 4-bus Test System load buses only}\label{fig:Image_001}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 7):

To align the captions use the `[t]` option of `minipage`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-4x3}
  \caption{{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont spy} Plot of 4-bus Test System
  \label{fig:Image_34}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-1x1}
  \caption{{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont spy} Plot of 4-bus Test System load buses only \label{fig:Image_001}}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to align the top of the figures, additionally use `\adjincludegraphics[...,valign=T]` from the `adjustbox` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \adjincludegraphics[width=1\linewidth,valign=T]{example-image-4x3}
  \caption{{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont spy} Plot of 4-bus Test System
  \label{fig:Image_34}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \adjincludegraphics[width=1\linewidth,valign=T]{example-image-1x1}
  \caption{{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont spy} Plot of 4-bus Test System load buses only \label{fig:Image_001}}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]