# Side-by-side figure alignment

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment

A question that I haven't seen directly asked or answered on the stack exchange is, how do I put two figures side-by-side in LaTex so that

1. The figures are center aligned (especially if the figures have a white background, the center alignment looks the best in my opinion); but
2. The captions of the two figures are top aligned.

If the figures are unrelated, or for whatever reason, you don't want to use subfigure, there isn't a great way to do this that I've seen.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371525/minipage-figure-caption-alignment only use \raisebox{-0.5\height){...) to center them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear, what is your problem and why you have use so complex code ... if the following is expected result:

[image]

then your code can be simpler, something as is in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% for move images baseline to vertical center of image

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=c]{example-image-duck}
    &   \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth,valign=c]{example-image-duck}   \\
\caption{The caption.}  \label{label1}
    &   \caption{The caption.}  \label{label2}
    \end{tabular*}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works other than the fact that the two figures do not seem to be very well centered in their respective columns; the result seems to be left aligned, but I only see centering commands.

Comment: @Kraig, you haven't right. For test, that images as well caption are centered vertically and horizontally, add table rules. And, as I mentioned in answer, your problem is not very clear. Do you like to have distance between images independent from image size?

Answer (score 1):

I propose to do that with the `floatrow` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% for move images baseline to vertical center of image

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
    \centering
        \captionsetup{textfont = it, labelfont=sc, labelsep=endash}
        \floatsetup{heightadjust = object, valign = c}
        \begin{floatrow}[2]\ffigbox[1.33\FBwidth]{\caption{The Virgin Spanking the Christ Child before Three Witnesses: André Breton, Paul Éluard, and the Painter}\label{MaxErnst36}}
        {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ernst_vierge}}
        \ffigbox[1.33\FBwidth]{\caption{Euclid}\label{MaxErnst45}}{ \includegraphics{euclid} }
        \end{floatrow}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this is to use the following

```
\begin{figure}
\newlength{\miniPageWidth}
\setlength{\miniPageWidth}{0.45\textwidth}   
\newcommand{\graphicOne}{example-image-a} 
\newcommand{\graphicTwo}{example-image-b} 
\newlength{\hOne}
\newlength{\hTwo}
\settoheight{\hOne}{\includegraphics[width=\miniPageWidth]{\graphicOne}}
\settoheight{\hTwo}{\includegraphics[width=\miniPageWidth]{\graphicTwo}}
\newlength{\padOne}
\newlength{\padTwo} 
\setlength{\padOne}{0pt}
\setlength{\padTwo}{0pt}
\ifthenelse{\hOne>\hTwo}{\setlength{\padTwo}{(\hOne-\hTwo)/2}}{
    \setlength{\padOne}{(\hTwo-\hOne)/2}}
\centering 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\miniPageWidth}
        \centering
        \vskip\padOne
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{\graphicOne}
        \vskip\padOne
        \caption{The caption.}    
        \label{label1}
    \end{minipage}
\hfill 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\miniPageWidth} 
        \centering
        \vspace\padTwo
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{\graphicTwo}
        \vskip\padTwo
        \caption{The caption.}        
        \label{label2}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

For display purposes, I have set the width of graphic two to 0.5\miniPageWidth and changed the captions to produce the following example graphic.

[image: Output]

The above code does not reflect these changes because I want the code above to be useable. To produce the above graphic, make the adjustments:

```
\settoheight{\hTwo}{\includegraphics[width=.5\miniPageWidth]{\graphicTwo}}

\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{\graphicTwo}

 \caption{Example caption one.}    

 \caption{This caption has \newline multiple lines.}
```

I'm unsure if this is the most appropriate way to do this. There are some old, somewhat related questions to this issue, but I didn't want this solution to be buried at the bottom of those posts. Hopefully someone gets some use out of this.

Comment: This answer more like as whyt you try so far ... you may consider to move it in your question.

Comment: @Zarko This is a working solution, not an attempt.

Comment: well, than please be so kind and extend your code fragment to an MWE, that people can simply test your solution. Regardless, that you solved your problem (which is not clear what it is)  yourseld, I wrote an alternative  possible solution ...